# What does pure function returning pure mean?

Tags: d, pure-function

What does it mean for a pure function to return pure?

```
pure int doubleMe(in int i) pure { return i * 2; }
```

The code compiles without giving `redundant storage class pure`, so I suppose this is not a bug?

// DMD 2.056

Comment: I've been trying to clean up the [tag:pure] tag, because it sometimes refers to pure virtual functions, sometimes to [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) and sometimes to [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_(programming_language)) - among others. But I don't know anything about [tag:d]. Could you confirm if my tag edit is appropriate? Would [tag:purely-functional] work for this question - I created [tag:pure-function], so if [tag:purely-functional] works I think it would be better to use the existing tag.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Pure as in [functional purity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), so pure-function would work for this question.  purely-functional, not so much.

Answer (score 4):

Pure is a function attribute. Function attributes can go before the return type or after the parameter list. It describes the function, not the return type, in both cases. Hence, there is no such thing as "returning pure".

It should raise an error, it's probably a bug. The same thing is ignored with some other attributes too, like @safe.

Comment: It wouldn't give `redundant storage class pure` anyway, since `pure` isn't a storage class. But still, it should probably be reporting an error.

Comment: It is parsed as a storage class, however: http://www.d-programming-language.org/declaration.html#StorageClass

Answer (score 0):

`pure int` probably should be ignored. However, I believe the reason why we have it is that a function may return a "pure function". In that case I think it is arguable whether it is a bug or not.

Comment: `pure` put before a return type always refers to the function. This is the same as with storage classes and other function attributes.